Could not find method exec() for arguments [ReactNativeModules$_getCommandOutput_closure16@37b03d5a]

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.


Could not find method exec() for arguments [ReactNativeModules$_getCommandOutput_closure16@37b03d5a] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProviderFactory_Decorated.


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 32s

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.


Could not find method exec() for arguments [ReactNativeModules$_getCommandOutput_closure16@37b03d5a] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProviderFactory_Decorated.


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 32

Did you find a solution?
